# trouble writting to text file and maintaining format python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having trouble writting to a text file and python while maintaining the formatting.

Here is my code. I want to write to a text file and maintain this exact formatting, but it puts all the text on the one line.

I have tried numerous methods to make this work like using a for loop, splitlines, etc

any help would be appreciated, thank you.

python 2.7.13

```
writethis = """
192.168.4.4
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status               Protocol
FastEthernet0/0            192.168.4.4     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
FastEthernet0/1            192.168.44.135  YES manual up                    up      
FastEthernet1/0            unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
192.168.4.2
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status               Protocol
FastEthernet0/0            192.168.4.2     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
FastEthernet0/1            192.168.2.2     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
FastEthernet1/0            192.168.3.2     YES NVRAM  up                    up      


"""




f = open("testtxt.txt",'ab')
for x in writethis.splitlines():
    f.write(x)



f.close()
```

Comment: `with open("testtxt.txt","w") as f: f.write(writethis)` ?

Comment: That solved it. Thank  you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The `write()` method of file objects writes the string passed as argument to the file, without adding newlines (in contrast to e.g. `print`). Splitting your data into lines will also remove the newlines that were in it.

Therefore, you need to explicitly add a newline:

```
f = open("testtxt.txt",'ab')
for x in writethis.splitlines():
    f.write(x)
    f.write('\n')
```

Alternatively, if you're not modifying the lines in your for loop, consider writing `writethis` into the file all at once. `write()` is able to handle quite large strings containing multiple lines.